How to make menu always visible in new IntelliJ IDEA?
IntelliJ IDEA has just updated and now to even get to menu (File, Navigate, Code, etc) you need to press the hamburger button first. This makes zero sense as there is enough screen real estate to just always display it, as well as one extra click and mouse movement for every operation you undertake.
What is the way to make that menu be always displayed as it was previously?

I agree, what a horrible, I repeat horrible UX. The person who thought this was a good idea must be fired immediately.

Found it almost immediately:
Right click somewhere on the toolbar with hamburger menu
"Always show menu in a separate toolbar"
"Do you want to restart IDEA" - yes.
Now it would be there always.
